# Unable to parse JSON data properly from Alomafire

Tags: json, swiftui, alamofire, jsondecoder, encodable

I know there are various threads on this but it seems like there's a fundamental flaw in my understanding of objects in Swift.

So I have the following function that returns a JSON response as expected:

```
   func executeGet( completion: @escaping ([[String:Any]]?, Error?) -> Void) {
                AF.request("https://myURL",
                           method:.get,
                           headers:headers).responseJSON{ response in
                    debugPrint(response) <- I get readable JSON response from here
                 
                    if let error = response.error {
                        completion(nil, error)
                    }
                    else if let jsonArray = response.value as? [[String:Any]]{
                        completion(jsonArray, nil)
                    }
                    else if let jsonDict = response.value as? [String:Any]{
                        completion([jsonDict], nil )
                    }
                    
                }
            }
```

And then I'm able to leverage the completion handler to read the JSON response outside of AL's scope:

```
            executeGet() { (json, error) in
                if let error = error{
                    print(error.localizedDescription)
                    
                }
                else if let json = json {
                    print(type(of:json)) <- did this for sanity check
                    print(json["result"][0]["capturedlists"]) <- Error No exact matches in call to subscript 
                }
            }
```

But I'm unable to just get the 'capturedLists' part of the JSON. The JSON snippet I need to capture looks as follows:

```
"capturedLists":{"Something":
    [{"Position":"1","A1":"a1","B1":"b1"},
    {"Position":"2","A2":"a2","B2":"b2"}]}}}
```

Can anyone help me figure out what am I doing wrong? I know usually you can get data from Json by something like response[a][0] but that doesn't work here for some reason.

EDIT: Upone suggestion I used Quicktype to get a struct for my response and got the following:

```
struct Welcome: Codable {
let statusCode: Int
let messageCode: String
let result: Result
 }

   // MARK: - Result
 struct Result: Codable {
let id: String
let inputParameters: InputParameters
let robotID: String
let runByUserID, runByTaskMonitorID: JSONNull?
let runByAPI: Bool
let createdAt, startedAt, finishedAt: Int
let userFriendlyError: JSONNull?
let triedRecordingVideo: Bool
let videoURL: String
let videoRemovedAt: Int
let retriedOriginalTaskID: String
let retriedByTaskID: JSONNull?
let capturedDataTemporaryURL: String
let capturedTexts: CapturedTexts
let capturedScreenshots: CapturedScreenshots
let capturedLists: CapturedLists

enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
    case id, inputParameters
    case robotID = "robotId"
    case runByUserID = "runByUserId"
    case runByTaskMonitorID = "runByTaskMonitorId"
    case runByAPI, createdAt, startedAt, finishedAt, userFriendlyError, triedRecordingVideo
    case videoURL = "videoUrl"
    case videoRemovedAt
    case retriedOriginalTaskID = "retriedOriginalTaskId"
    case retriedByTaskID = "retriedByTaskId"
    case capturedDataTemporaryURL = "capturedDataTemporaryUrl"
    case capturedTexts, capturedScreenshots, capturedLists
}
 }
```

Comment: Any can’t be decoded, you can use “json serialization” or a real model look at QuickType.io

Comment: Pardon my ignorance but I'm not sure what you mean. Are you saying I can use Quicktype.io to create a struct for the json response?

Comment: Yes you can use that website

Comment: So I used that to get a struct but I'm not sure how I would use that in my function. Would you mind showing that to me? I updated the question with what I code from that website.

Comment: I don’t have an alamofire setup for samples, maybe someone else will be able to give you some code but QuickType gives you everything you need to make a call (without alamofire) and decode.

Comment: You will need a JSONDecoder though you aren’t actually decoding right now you are just trying to force it.

Comment: @loremipsum so I was able to understand it. Now I'm using the struct from quicktype in my function. The only issue is that when I call JSONDecoder for decoding json it always says " Cannot convert value of type '[[String : Welcome]]' to expected argument type 'Data'. " My welcome struct was obtained from Quicktype :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.responseJSON` is deprecated. Don't use it.

The error occurs because `json["result"]` returns `Any` but the compiler must know the static type for the subsequent index subscription.

As you have a `Decodable` model AF provides `responseDecodable`. Change your function to

```
func executeGet( completion: @escaping (Result<Welcome,Error>) -> Void) {
            AF.request("https://myURL",
                       method:.get,
                       headers:headers).responseDecodable(of: Welcome.self) { response in

        switch response.result {
            case .success(let welcome): 
                completion(.success(welcome))

            case .failure(let error): 
                completion(.failure(error))
        }
    }

}
```

which can even be simplified to

```
func executeGet( completion: @escaping (Result<Welcome,Error>) -> Void) {
            AF.request("https://myURL",
                       method:.get,
                       headers:headers).responseDecodable(of: Welcome.self) { response in

        completion(response.result)
    }

}
```

And call it

```
executeGet() { result in
    switch result {
        case .success(let welcome): print(welcome)
        case .failure(let error): print(error)
    }
}
```

If you get an error the model doesn't match the JSON and the error tells you exactly what's wrong

Comment: Oh interesting. Lemme try that. BTW, I just updated my Result struct since the previous once wasn't accurate. Does the code still apply to this struct? Apologies for any inconvenience :/

Comment: I have no idea because I don't know the whole JSON.